# How can i make the XPATH FORMAT as i wanted to (customized) in DataStage?

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I'm literally confused how to make the XPATH in DataStage, because i've tried some things from Google and that gave me no hope or whatsoever.

What i wanted is something like this :

```
<redcords ACCOUNT_NO="1020006187840" BALANCE="0" BALANCE_IDR="0" CIF="1520001183600" CURRENCY="JPY " CURRRATE="1" CUSTOMER_ID="ETL" OPENING_DATE="22/01/2014" PRODUCT_TYPE="ZJPY      " RATE="131.2" REKENING="31/07/2019" STATUS="7000299383" UPDATED_BY="0" UPDATED_DATE="7000299383"/>
```

I mean like where can i configure this XML Format in XPATH? And customized it as i wanted to?

Comment: Not enough information provided! What is the base data?  which stages are involved? What is the use case? etc.

Comment: Umm sorry , in this question i've provided more details maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607487/how-change-the-xpath-and-xml-output-format-in-datastage