# How change the XPATH and XML output format in DataStage?

Tags: xml, xpath, etl, datastage

I HAVE some problem in XPATH In XML Output

I Want The Output Like

```
<categories>
  <category NAME="A">
    <redcord a="1"></redcord>
    <redcord a="2"></redcord>
  </category>
  <category NAME="B">
    <redcord b="ASD"></redcord>
    <redcord b="QWE"></redcord>
  </category>
</categories>
```

I HAVE XPATH LIKE :

```
/categories/category[@NAME="A"]/redcord/@a
```

AND

```
/categories/category[@NAME="B"]/redcord/@b
```

The Output that i've been making is

```
<categories>
  <category NAME="A">
    <redcord a="1" b="ASD"></redcord>
    <redcord a="2" b="QWE"></redcord>
  </category>
</categories>
```

Anyone have any idea how to make the XML format as i wanted above?
Fyi : I'm using Oracle Database , Datastage

Comment: Your question is unclear; is the first xml snippet in your question your desired output and the 2nd your actual output? If so, please edit your question and post the source xml against which you run these two xpath expressions.

Comment: The first snippet is the output that i'm desired, and the last snippet is the progress that i've tried. 
Thankyou so much for responding!

Comment: Got it. So can you post the source html/xml (or at least a representative portion)?

Comment: Oh okay sorry maybe i haven't explain it a little bit, but the source is from Database (Tables) and i wanted to make the XML from it by using Datastage

Comment: I've tried to figure out and the XPATH and DataStage think the 2 category tag is the same. but still i've change it here and there but makes no difference